# strange NullPointerException on String

Tags: android, string, nullpointerexception

I keep getting crashes recorded on GP developer console:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.xyz.abc.quizstart.calctracks(SourceFile:690)
```

line 690 has this:

```
687     public void calctracks(){
688         TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.trackcounttext);
689         Spinner spin= (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
690         String val ="3"; 
691         questionsperplayer=3;
692         val = spin.getSelectedItem().toString();
693         if(val!=""){
694             questionsperplayer = Integer.parseInt(val);
695             totalrequiredquestionsandanswers=playerList.size()*questionsperplayer*4;
696             t.setText(totalrequiredquestionsandanswers + " music tracks required");
697         }else{
698             t.setText("");
699         }
700         
701     }
```

I cannot replicate NPE on emulator or on my two phones or tablet. Judging by the number of admob clicks I know many users are using the app fine without this issue. However I get about 8 of these a week.

Surely declaring a string and and setting a value to it cannot cause this?

Any ideas what to try?

Comment: are you sure that line 690 is correct? Maybe you changed some code and now the errors don't match to your code any more?

Comment: I can assure you, that the current line 690 is not throwing this error, try re-running this and you'll be able to see that it's probably line 692 (I suspect spin is null)

Comment: agree with ubergesundheit and don't compare Strings the way you did! If(!"".equals(val))

Comment: Sometimes the lines can be out, put a break point at the start of the function and step through.

Comment: Also you need to camelCase your variables. If you right click on them and go to refactor->rename (in Eclipse) it will take care renaming all instances of the variable for you. totalrequiredquestionsandanswers looks much better as totalRequiredQuestionsAndAnswers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**try**

```
if(spin.getSelectedItem()!=null){    
   val = spin.getSelectedItem().toString();
}

if(!val.equals("")){
  questionsperplayer = Integer.parseInt(val);
  totalrequiredquestionsandanswers=playerList.size()*questionsperplayer*4;
  t.setText(totalrequiredquestionsandanswers + " music tracks required");
 }else{
    t.setText("");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You  may be not selected the item. Try this one

if(spin.getSelectedItem()!=null)

{

```
   val = spin.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

}

Comment: that might fix it, thaks

Answer (score 2):

The source line the exception mentions is probably from a different version of the app. I suspect the issue is more likely in line 692 in your posted code. If `getSelectedItem()` returns `null`.

NOTE: `if (val != "")` seems to be buggy as you test with `val.equals("")` for equality of strings. Also, using `val.length() == 0` is the best IMHO.

Comment: true have been caught out with != on string before, will update.

Answer (score 0):

Place a breakpoint at the start of the function and step through. I suspect that the line number is incorrect.

Comment: This is coming from an app deployed to clients as I understood. :)

Comment: Ah sorry yes, I misread. The crashes are from the Google Play console. In that case I would suspect it was possibly line 692 and something like ProGuard has caused the line numbers to be out?

Comment: yes this is proguarded then remapped using retrace.jar. The GP crash is from the same source / version of the app

Comment: I could be wrong but I just can't see how you would get a NPE on that line... I would suggest trying some of the code improvements put forward in other answers and then see if the NPE moves in the new version.